# When we hit ldap we face W3C schema namespace

Tags: namespaces, schema, w3c

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid schema document passed to AbstractDataBinding.addSchemaDocument, not in W3C schema namespace: schema
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:343)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:489)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Comment: we need a question. We also need context and (ideally) a sample of code. Pasting an error message in isolation is lazy and unlikely to get the best responses

Answer (score -1):

This shows ldap is not passed with the correct parameters. So if you can pass the mandatory parameters correctly then it will resolve the issue